# Center of Gravity and Coordinate Systems

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

**In below figure**

[image]

I need to find the coordinates of center of gravity which are $x$' and $y$' in order to find distances of $OG$ and $OS$. To explain the figure; $x^q+y^q<=1$, area of $ROP$ is not circular because degree of $q$ is bigger than $2$.
I need the solution for any $x^q+y^q<=1$ , for any $q$ which is between $3$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which figure?

Comment: The tag "algebraic-geometry" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: I put the figure but I can not view it myself , can you see it?

Comment: Your figure shows `x + y < 1` !

And unless OP is oblique unwillingly, `(x, y)` isn't enough to describe the geometry.

Comment: Yes you are right $x^q+y^q<=1$ , I've corrected, and OP should be straight, if it seems oblique its my drawing mistake...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you can compute the area and first order moments under the curve, you are (nearly) done.

The explicit equation of the curve can be written

```
y = (1 - x^q)^(1/q)
```

The area is given by the integral of

```
(1 - x^q)^(1/q) dx
```

and the `x`/`y` moments, respectively by

```
x (1 - x^q)^(1/q) dx

(1 - x^q)^(2/q) dx
```

By a change of variable `t:= x^q`, all these integrands are turned to a form

```
t^α (1 - t)^ß dt
```

known as the incomplete Beta function. So there is no closed-form solution for general exponents.

You have two choices:

- use the Beta function from a mathematical library,
- use numerical integration (Simson's rule).

Comment: Yves, I've really appreciate your contribution, I've tried numerical integration (Simson's rule)but its more about finding sliced parts of integral, but in my case  I need a part both limited in x and y axis. As a starting point can I find a solution for specific q value e.g. paraboles for $x^3+y^3<=1$ and  x,y so that $x^3+y^3<=1$

Comment: @adamsx: there is no problem subtracting the upper and lower boundaries.